# Running django app as a service and it failing to load the base templates

Tags: django, service, django-templates

I have created this django appraisal app and I am running it on my company premises server and did not want to  have to run in with cmd for obvious reasons. So I created this simple service that runs it on the a certain port. The problem is that all css fails to load and the base templates cannot be found when I run it. It is worth noting that when I run it from cmd everything loads perfectly but when I start the service, the base templates cannot be found.

Here is the service I am using:

```
<service>
  <id>appraisal</id>
  <name>Appraisal</name>
  <description>This service runs Pergamon Appraisal tool</description>
  <executable>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe</executable>
  <arguments>C:\perg_appraisal\pergamon_appraisal\pergamon\manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9190</arguments>
  <logpath>C:\perg_appraisal\pergamon_appraisal\service_logs</logpath>
  <log mode="roll"></log>
</service>
```

Here is my BASE_DIR path in settings:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Here is my templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and here is my static files urls:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

What could be making my base templates not visible when running it as a service?